# REGEX where img tag does not have alt

Tags: html, regex, image, alt

I am trying to write a regex that looks for an img tag where there is no alt attribute.

Here is the regex.

```
<img\s+src.+^(?!alt).+$
```

Here are some samples

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
<img src="smiley2.gif" height="42" width="42">
<img src="smiley3.gif" alt="Smiley face Three" height="42" width="42">
```

Here is a link to regex101
https://regex101.com/r/Z5vkQb/3/

Comment: Try `<img\b(?![^>]*? alt=)[^>]*>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If within the same line, you can use this,

```
<img(?!.*\s+alt\s*=).+$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z5vkQb/5)**

Comment: `<img src="whatever.png" title="should match but alt= in here makes it fail ;)" />` - Using regex to parse HTML ***does not work!!!***

Answer (score 2):

[Don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/507674).

You haven't specified which language you're using, but chances are good you have a DOM parser available.

For example, in JavaScript, you can just do this:

```
var imgs_with_no_alt = document.querySelectorAll("img:not([alt])");
```

In PHP you would need something like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("your HTML here");
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");
foreach($images as $image) {
    if( $image->getAttribute("alt")) continue;
    // do something to $image here, which doesn't have an [alt] attribute
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression:

```
<img[^>]*alt=[^>]*>
```

Comment: `<img src="salt.png" />` makes you salty because your expression fails.

Comment: Include the `=` after the `alt`. e.g. `<img[^>]*alt=[^>]*>`

Comment: `<img src="dynamic.php?salt=true" />`

Comment: `<img[^>]*\s+alt=[^>]*>`

Comment: `<img src="whatever.png" title="Am I being annoying yet? alt=regexes do not work." />`